# What is dots-per-CSS-inch and dots-per-physical-inch

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

I've received this message from Chrome Developer Tools console tab when access [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/):

> Consider using 'dppx' units instead of 'dpi', as in CSS 'dpi' means
>   dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond
>   to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: only
>   screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), not all, not all, only
>   screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and (min-resolution:
>   2dppx)

It's in blue color so I'm assuming that's not a warning or error. So why did I encounter this message? How can I get rid of it or it's just a problem with `jsfiddle` itself?

Comment: It's actually a Chrome debug message and there's not much you can do about it since it's based on the code being run on jsFiddle. You can filter out the debug messages so you don't see them, but that's about it.

Comment: There should be a way to disable this annoying message.

Answer (score 39):

This is related, but perhaps not limited, to Apples Retina displays. These displays have a higher pixel density than previously used screens but the browser still acts as if it has the same number of pixels.

E.g. the iPhone 3GS had a display with 320 x 480 pixels but the iPhone 4 was released with 640 x 960 pixels. However, instead of showing website at that resolution the browser pretended to have a resolution 320 x 480 pixels.

This leads on to the invention of CSS-pixels. If you specify that something is `width:100px` in CSS it will be `100` physicals pixels on a normal display but `200` physical pixels on a retina display. A iPhone 3GS and iPhone 4 both have the same `dpi` (as it is based on pretend CSS-pixels) but very different `dppx` (as that is based on the real physical pixels).

You can use `dppx` to detect when a client has a high pixel density screen and serve it a different styling even if the client's browser pretends like it doesn't have that high  pixel density.

```
 .comp {
     background-image: url(image.png);
 }

 @media only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) {
     .comp {
         background-image: url(image@2x.png);
     }
 }
```

More info here on CSS-pixels: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resolution

Comment: This is horrible. Just give me the device's physical dpi and I'll be happpy, Google and Mozilla.