# Chrome warning: Consider using 'dppx' units instead of 'dpi'

Tags: google-chrome

I get the following message in Chrome:

```
Consider using 'dppx' units instead of 'dpi', as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-resolution: 144dpi)
```

When I click on the referenced location it takes me to the first line of the HTML file which does not have any code. I did a search for the 'dpi' but didn't find anything. Please advice.

Comment: Did you look in the css files?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yeah, it's so weird.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is dots-per-CSS-inch and dots-per-physical-inch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971331/what-is-dots-per-css-inch-and-dots-per-physical-inch)

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Google Chrome as addressed here:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336276

Should be fixed in the latest release they say. Are you still experiencing this issue?